# nginx reverse proxy pass/redirect not working

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to achieve the below with nginx -

I have 2 docker containers running on a server once container runs nginx on port 80 & takes requests from AWS application load balancer. Then based on the path in the URL, it is supposed to redirect to one of 3 ports on the other docker container. The applications running in the second docker container serve content on their own paths.

Example - When I type `https://example.com/story/fairy`, Nginx is supposed to parse `/story/fairy` & pass it to the other docker container on port 9091. The returned data from the app may be on path `/_myownpath/page1/`. The browser URL at the end of it should look  - `https://example.com/story/fairy/_myownpath/page1`.

Then if there are other links on this returned page & the user clicks on them, nginx should pass just the new path to the app listening on port 9091 & say the new content returned will be on path `/_newpath/story_page_11`. The browser URL should now look `https://example.com/story/fairy/_newpath/story_page_11` & so on.

I've pulled my hairs apart playing with nginx config & haven't been able to get my head around and get this right.

Some of the configs I've tried are

Tried proxy pass

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;
    
        location /story/fairy/ {
            # Reject requests with unsupported HTTP method
            if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)$) {
                return 405;
            }
    
            # Only requests matching the whitelist expectations will
            # get sent to the application server
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:9091/;
            proxy_redirect http://localhost:9091/ https://$server_name/;
        }
}
```

Tried redirecting

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /awsmap/dev/ {
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)$) {
            return 405;
        }

        return 301 http://localhost:9091/;
    }
```

Tried re-writing

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /story/fairy {
        rewrite ^/story(.*)$ / break;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        absolute_redirect off;
    }

    location ^~ /story\/fairy/ {
    rewrite ^/story(.*)$ / break;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:9091;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        absolute_redirect off;
    }

}
```

I've got very little experience with nginx. Stuck at this point getting this to work.

I'd truly appreciate ay help to get this working please.

Comment: Can you provide the logs when you try to access to your URL for each configuration ?
You can use the command `tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log` to see in real time the error log
You can use the command `tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log` to see in real time the access log

Answer (score 0):

Different docker containers cannot reach each other via `localhost` (by default). The recommended way to have a connection between to containers is for them to use the same [docker-network](https://docs.docker.com/network/) they can communicate using the container names as the hostnames. So changing the `proxy_pass` line to your application host, should fix it.

E.G:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location /story/fairy/ {
        # Reject requests with unsupported HTTP method
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD|OPTIONS|PUT|DELETE)$) {
            return 405;
        }

        # Only requests matching the whitelist expectations will
        # get sent to the application server
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://app-host:9091/;
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Using docker compose all containers share the same [docker-network](https://docs.docker.com/network/), and you can/should use it. See [explanation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) .